# Is there a was to pass a hence to MySQL's sub query to only look at some records?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I wish the MySQL optimizer was smart enough, I would not be asking question like this.

Here is my dilemma. I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM accordi.accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN accordi.df_answers_text AS t3 ON t3.related_to = a.account_id AND t3.field_id = 3
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    p.related_to
    , o.field_id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(o.label SEPARATOR " | ") AS labels
    FROM accordi.df_answer_predefined AS p
    INNER JOIN accordi.df_fields_options AS o ON o.option_id = p.option_id 
    WHERE o.is_place_holder = 0 AND o.field_id = 1 AND p.field_id = 1
    GROUP BY p.related_to, o.field_id
) AS s ON s.related_to = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_id = 1;
```

MySQL will process this query in the following order "give and take"

1. MySQL will pull all the results in the sub query from the tables
2. creates a temp table "with no index". (there is about 2 million records here)
3. Runs the first part of the query "one record only since I have a where clause" and it joins them.

The problem here is that the optimizer is not smart enough to know this "since the sub query is joined to the outer query `ON related_to` then the only `related_to` values that are needed from the sub query are the values that will be used by the outer query.) In MySQL defense there probably a good reason for this behavior.

Question: is there a way I can add a hence in the query where the optimizer will pass something like " AND related_to = 1 " to the sub query and instead of pulling 2 million records now will pull only 1 in the sub query?

Just to be clear I know I can write this query and will solve my issue

```
SELECT * 
FROM accordi.accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN accordi.df_answers_text AS t3 ON t3.related_to = a.account_id AND t3.field_id = 3
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    p.related_to
    , o.field_id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(o.label SEPARATOR " | ") AS labels
    FROM accordi.df_answer_predefined AS p
    INNER JOIN accordi.df_fields_options AS o ON o.option_id = p.option_id 
    WHERE o.is_place_holder = 0 AND o.field_id = 1 AND p.field_id = 1 AND p.related_to = 1
    GROUP BY p.related_to, o.field_id
) AS s ON s.related_to = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_id = 1;
```

However, I need to add hence because the sub query is actually a view where I join table to it. Therefore, I can not add the extra clause

My actual query "when joining the table on the view" looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM accordi.accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN accordi.df_answers_text AS t3 ON t3.related_to = a.account_id AND t3.field_id = 3
LEFT JOIN s ON s.related_to = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_id = 1;
```

And the view looks like this

```
CREATE VIEW s AS
SELECT 
p.related_to
, o.field_id
, GROUP_CONCAT(o.label SEPARATOR " | ") AS labels
FROM accordi.df_answer_predefined AS p
INNER JOIN accordi.df_fields_options AS o ON o.option_id = p.option_id 
WHERE o.is_place_holder = 0 AND o.field_id = 1 AND p.field_id = 1
GROUP BY p.related_to, o.field_id;
```